# Google Classroom Profile photo auth access

Tags: javascript, google-api, authorization, google-oauth, google-classroom

I'm attempting to get access to student photos in Google Classroom. I can succesfully get access to the photo URLs using the code below. However, when the browser attempts to access the student photo, it gets a 403 error. Do I need to authorise the IMG tags (and how does one even do that?), or is there a different step I'm missing?

```
function getStudents(courseId) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('content');
    gapi.client.classroom.courses.students.list({
        courseId: courseId,
        pageSize: 0
    }).then(function(response) {
        var ss = response.result.students;

        for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
            appendPre(ss[i]['profile']['name']['fullName']);
            var imageContent = document.createElement('img');
            var photoUrl = ss[i].profile.photoUrl
            if (photoUrl.substring(0,4) != "http") {
                photoUrl = "https:" + photoUrl;  // bug in API doesn't always include protocol
            }
            imageContent.setAttribute('src', photoUrl);
            appendPre(photoUrl)
            pre.appendChild(imageContent);

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error 403** in Classroom API with the ClassroomApiDisabled message means that you are not authorized to access the data:

> ClassroomApiDisabled indicates that the requesting user does not have
>   access to the Classroom API.
>
> Possible Action: Direct the user to instructions on [enabling
>   Classroom data
>   access](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6250906). Also
>   see
>   [NotGoogleAppsUser](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Access.Errors#notgoogleappsuser),
>   as the user may be using the wrong account.